# Bad handshake (1043) between PHP 4.4.9 and MySQL 5.7.8

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue when trying to connect to MySQL database from an old system to a new one. I received the error code 1043. It seems related to bad handshake. No issue when doing the opposite.

Interesting thing is if I kill the mysqld process from the new system, I have no error from mysql_connect!

Something to remember. I can't upgrade the old system to the new PHP and MySQL. No more space and difficulty to recompile them to my platform.

**Old system configuration:**

- PHP 4.4.9
- MySQL 4.1.18
- Using mysql_connect() to get access to the new system.
- my.cnf has the remote user name and password to connect to the new system.

**New system configuration:**

- PHP 7.1.2
- MySQL 5.7.8
- MySQL has a remote user and password

The PHP code from the old system looks like this:

```
$cn = mysql_connect($address, $user, $password);
if (!$cn)
{
    die("Could not open $table database: " . $db);
}

mysql_select_db($db, $cn);
```

After that, here what I tried:

1. Because I thought it could be a password hashing issue, I tried the OLD_PASSWORD() (`set password for 'remote_user'@'%'=OLD_PASSWORD('password')`), but it has been removed in version 5.7.8
2. Same thing with the old_passwords flag. Has been removed.
3. Set an empty password to the new system database remote user: `set password for 'remote_user'@'%'='';`
4. Set the --skip-grant-tables to the new system's mysqld process

Now, I do not know what I could do anymore. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP 4.4 was released 8 years prior to MySQL 5.7 ... I wouldn't think there's even a 1% chance of this working.

Comment: yeah, this is what It think also, but maybe someone has a work around?

Comment: My cassette tape won't work on my MP3 player...

Comment: @David You'd get better results if you invested time into upgrading rather than making ancient software work.